# How to calculate this simple percentage question

Tags: math, percentage, percentile

What would be the

```
x% + y% of z
```

in format

```
a% of z
```

Such that

```
y%(x%(z)) + x%(z)=a%(z)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming problem

Answer (score 1):

Taking a percent, say `N%`, is the same as multiplying by `N/100`. For instance, `30%(u) = 30/100*u`. So,

```
y%(x%(z)) = y/100*x%(z)
```

and

```
y%(x%(z)) + x%(z) = y/100*x%(z) + x%(z)
                  = (y/100 + 1)*x%(z)
                  = (y+100)/100*x%(z)
                  = (y+100)/100)*x/100*z
```

thus

```
a = (y+100)/100*x
```